# Kubernetes & Gitlab: How to store password for private registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I want to run my application that is hosted in a private container registry on a Kubernetes cluster. I followed the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) and created a secret like this:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> \
      --docker-username=<your-name> \
      --docker-password=<your-pword> \
      --docker-email=<your-email>
```

which is used in my deployment like this:

```
      containers:
      - image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/xxxx
        name: dockerdemo
        resources: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

K8s is now able to pull the image from my private registry. Anyhow I don't feel comfortable that my user and password are stored in plain text in the cluster. Is there a better/more secure way to give the K8s cluster access to the registry maybe by a token?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hence I am using [Gitlab](https://www.gitlab.com) the solution for me know is not to store my user credentials in Kubernetes. Instead I am using a Deploy Token that can be removed any time and that only has access to the container registry.

The following steps are necessary here:

- Open Gitlab and go to your project
- Settings > Access Tokens > Add new token
- Create a token with scope `read_registry`
- Create secret in K8S: `kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=<token_username> --docker-password=<token> -n <kubernetes_namespace>`

Thank you @Jonas for your links but this solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: To add on, if your deployment is pointed to specific `namespace`, remember to create your Gitlab secret in the same namespace too. Just add `-n yourNameSpaceName` at the end of your create secret command.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyhow I don't feel comfortable that my user and password are stored in plain text in the cluster. Is there a better/more secure way to give the K8s cluster access to the registry maybe by a token?

See [Encrypting Secret Data at Rest](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/)
 for how to ensure that your Secrets is encrypted in etcd.

Alternatively you can consider to use [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) to store secrets. See e.g. [How Monzo bank security team handle secrets](https://monzo.com/blog/2019/10/11/how-our-security-team-handle-secrets)

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, I will checkout the links.

Comment: Can you expand either of these to give more complete details, and not just external links?  (I’d be especially curious to see a complete Vault setup.)